# Integrate Pop-Up "notification" in java graphical output

Tags: java, swing

I have the following problem:

While processing something in the background, a graphical output is shown and permanently updated. I would like to add a pop-up textbox, which is displayed only a few moments, to show that an predefined event occured. (basically something like a notification).

Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "graphical output" so you can't use JPanel?

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems like I had only part of the code. Graphical Output was just a class that extended JPanel. Stupid little me ... :S

Answer (score 0):

Usualy a status bar is an option for you (can be made using JPanel). Alternative you can use popups (example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingPopUpComponents.htm)) or messages for [TrayIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Comment: Status bar is quite a nice idea. Thank you a lot